# How to integrate SFMC SDK in a framework?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

We have a framework (say its name is `MyFramework`) which wraps SFMC SDK and link it statically, in this framework we integrate SFMC SDK via CocoaPods：
[image]

But the SDK crashes when I call `sfmc_configureWithURL:` or `sfmc_configureWithDictionary`, I stepped into the assembly code and found the SDK failed to load some of its CoreData Model which means SFMC SDK didn't find its bundle directory.

This is because the SDK is using `main bundle path` to find its bundle directory. I don't post the assembly code of SFMC SDK here because I'm afraid this maybe illegal. The related code of this issue is around `SFMCDatabase.m:290` of version 6.3.3

I believe using `+[NSBundle bundleForClass:]` instead of `+[NSBundle mainBundle]` can fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sven-song, the difficulty with using `bundleForClass` in this instance is that it will return `MarketingCloudSDK.framework` (where the code lives) - not the parent of the .framework (from which we can call the rest of the code - `URLForResource:@"MarketingCloudSDK" withExtension:@"bundle"]`).

Without explicitly walking the filesystem paths, there's no other way to get our framework's "parallel" resources bundle using NSBundle (without knowing the "root" - i.e. the `mainBundle`). Walking paths outside of our bundle *could* be fragile.

I'll make a note to look into this more but can make no promises about a different outcome here.

Additionally - even if we *could* do this, it is not on our roadmap right now for building out (and supporting) a solution for embedding our SDK within other deliverable frameworks in this manner. I do not know what it would take to ensure proper operation across all configurations, customers and delivery mechanisms.